# get shell version of run configuration in a JetBrains IDE

Tags: shell, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I'm using PyCharm, but I assume that this is similar for all the JetBrains products.

PyCharm has a very convenient UI for editing runtime configurations.
But currently I feel like there is too much UI between me and the actual code execution.
I'm using python + docker and I would like to know what exactly the IDE is doing.

Is it possible to export a runtime configuration to terminal commands?

If you start a run configuration, you get a 'run' tab at the bottom of your window which shows a shortened version of the command. Basically the interpreter and the script. But it definitely doesn't show everything that is going on (for example, in my python+docker setup the published ports are not shown).
Playing around with the UI, I couldn't find the shell version of my runtime config.
And in the [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration.html), I didn't find anything either.